# iOS-How to display 40 images in one prototype Cell inside UITableview using array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I'm creating online tutorial app.In that i have 40 questions.I want to display the result for that questions using green image for correct and red color image for incorrect answers.I need to display this 40 images inside the single prototype cell.I want to know in swift.

Comment: refer this link http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/ and https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/ more idea for how to use tableview

Comment: I need to display 40 image inside singe row in a Cell.

Comment: @Sri Sumi Custom `UITableViewCell` with 40 `UIImageView`

Comment: You need to try something, provide any code you are having problems with. Just asking for an answer is not what SO is about.

Comment: No other way?Like for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table view is designed to show multiple items in a scrolling list, not just one item.  It sounds more like you want to have a table view with 40 rows, each of which displays the answer given for the question.  You could set that up easily like so:

```
// This is your prototype cell configured in interface builder
class ResultTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var answerImageView: UIImageView!

    var correct: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            let imageName = self.correct ? "correct_image" : "incorrect_image"
            if let image = UIImage(named: imageName ) {
                self.answerImageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }

}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    struct Answer {
        let isCorrect: Bool
    }

    var answers = [Answer]() {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath ) as? ResultTableViewCell {
            cell.correct = self.answers[ indexPath.row ].isCorrect
            return cell
        }

        fatalError( "Could not load cell" )
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.answers.count
    }
}
```

Comment: now i have posted the screenshot, im asking like that in single row.Please take a look.

Comment: Okay, then you should do that as a `UICollectionView`, which works similar to a table view but provides a grid-like layout.  Each of your collection view cells would have an image and a label to show the number.  If you don't need more than one of these views, than you simply don't need a table view.

Comment: However, if you're saying you need to have multiple rows, each of which contains these 40 widgets, than you should put your collection view inside a table view cell.

Comment: No problem.  If that solves it, would you mind marking the answer as correct? :)